# JPA Hibernate bidirectional relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA and have some problems in understanding bidirectional relations.

I have the entities Job and Execution. 1 Job belongs to exactly 1 Execution and vice versa. So, I wanted to use the onetoone relation.

My code looks like following:

```
@Entity
public class Execution {
        ....
       @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,optional=false)
        private Job job;
        ....
}

@Entity
public class Job{
    ......
   @OneToOne(mappedBy="job",optional=false)
    private Execution execution;
    .....
 }
```

I set optional=false for both fields. As expected, hibernate throws an exception if I try to persist an Execution object which has a Null Job object.
But persisting a Job object with a Null Execution object is possible, although I set optional=false.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a bit more information about yuor database-structure?

Comment: Doesnt hibernate create the database structure based on my annotations?

Comment: It can, but this is not recommended for production and I never used it. Generally I think you should design your database and then create the entities to fit this structure. What db are you using?

Comment: What gets persisted to your db exactly? Is the foreign key for the execution object NULL as well? I guess a execution object get created on the fly somewhere while persisting or the database-structure should be altered... but that's really just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following annotation.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
```

Comment: but that isn't a jpa annotation

Comment: Sorry, try: @Column(nullable = false)